# Using ScheduledExecutorService drastically slows down execution

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, scheduledexecutorservice

I need to limit the execution time of some methods so am using `ScheduledExecutorService` not to add concurrency but to enforce a timeout.

```java
public class Task {
    private static final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors
            .newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public abstract Callable<Result> getCallable(Target target);

    public Result processTarget(Target target) {
        try {
            ScheduledFuture<List<Result>> future = scheduler.schedule(
                        getCallable(target), 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            return future.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

While this code works, the performance is unacceptable. For some concrete subclasses, the call to `future.get()` takes 10 seconds, even if the call to the `Callable` function takes only milliseconds when called directly. Increasing the thread pool size makes no difference.

For example, one concrete subclass returns a `Callable` that runs PMD programmatically.

```java
public class PmdGrader extends Task {
    @Override
    public Callable<Result> getCallable(final Target target) {
        return () -> {
            try (PmdAnalysis analysis = createAnalysis()) {
                analysis.files().addFileOrDirectory(target.toPath());
                Report report = analysis.performAnalysisAndCollectReport();
                return produceResults(report);
            }
        };
    }
```

Before adding `ScheduledExecutorService` (i.e., when doing the work in the main thread), unit tests involving `PmdGrader` took 13-696 ms each. After adding concurrency, some tests took the same amount of time, while others took approximately 10 seconds more than their original times. If I increase the timeout from 10 seconds to 15 seconds, those tests take an additional 5 seconds. In other words, instead of being a maximum time (as I intended), the timeout is acting as a minimum time.

**Questions**

1. Is there a way to use `ScheduledExecutorService` without this huge performance hit.
2. Is there a better library (whether included with Java or external)?

Comment: it will *always* take 10 seconds! The task is being scheduled with a **delay** of seconds. Check the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule(java.util.concurrent.Callable,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)): "*Submits a value-returning one-shot task that becomes enabled **after the given delay**.*" (my emphasis) - it is not a timeout

Comment: @user16320675 D'oh!

Comment: @user16320675 Do you want to answer this question, or do you think I should just delete it?

Answer (score 0):

As user16320675 helpfully pointed out, I misunderstood the API: The argument to `ScheduledExecutorService.schedule()` specifies when to *start* the task, not when to end it.

The corrected code uses [`ExecutorService.submit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.util.concurrent.Callable-) and [`Future.get(long, TimeUnit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) as shown:

```java
public class Task {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public abstract Callable<Result> getCallable(Target target);

    public Result processTarget(Target target) {
        try {
            Future<List<Result>> future = executor.submit(getCallable(target));
            return future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException | TimeoutException | ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```